# linux when setting my latex PATH the PATH only maintains its value for the duration of the terminal window if i exit i have to reset everytime

Tags: linux, latex

**ALSO POSTED HERE i was not aware for tex.stackexchange before i made this post, so sorry for the double/cross post here is the link to the other tex.stackexchange post**

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153949/linuxnew-to-latex-path-to-latex-is-resetting-every-time-exit-the-terminal

I am trying to learn latex and i am running linux mint 15 x64. I have installed "texlive" and followed this installation guide:

http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

The problem i am having is, as the title suggests when i set my PATH variable to the latex directory, it works fine for one terminal window only, if i exit that terminal window the PATH no longer points to the latex install, thus i have to reset it every time which is rather annoying.

I am using the following command:

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux/:$PATH
```

then when i do:

echo $PATH i get this result:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux/:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

and i can do this:

```
latex --version

pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
kpathsea version 6.1.1
Copyright 2013 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.5.16; using libpng 1.5.16
Compiled with zlib 1.2.7; using zlib 1.2.7
Compiled with xpdf version 3.03
```

which is as expected, but when i close the terminal window, and re open it i get the following:

```
echo $PATH
```

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx <--- missing the latex path

and when i check the version:

```
latex --version:
The program 'latex' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-base
```

i have also tried doing the same as the super-user, i get the same end product.

Any have a solution to this problem?

Thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the path in the `.bashrc` file or `.bash_profile`
Adding

```
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux/:$PATH
```

Comment: just added it to the bottom of bash.bashrc now, i assume a reset is needed for it to take effect.

Comment: You can use `source ~/.bashrc` in the terminal and you won't need to restart... And if it didn't take effect you only need to restart the terminal app not the whole machine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that putting

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux/:$PATH
```

in your .bashrc will accomplish what you want